# Recommended way to handle Thymeleaf Spring MVC AJAX Forms and their error messages

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

What is the recommended way to handle AJAX forms and their error messages on the Thymeleaf side of things?

I currently have a Spring controller which returns a JSON overview of fields and their respective error messages, but having to resort to using fully handwritten JQuery (or just regular Javascript) just feels a bit wrong, and slow; especially because of the large amount of forms I intend to have in the application.

Comment: There is no right, wrong or recommended way to do this. It really depends on how your application is setup, your MVC layers, and what you want to display. Your options include alerts, fragments, grouped messages etc. I use multiple methods depending on what i want to return to user and in what format.

Comment: Well, I mostly am looking for the fastest way. RAD and all. So I can quickly build a good looking frontend for my backend which requires more engineering.

Comment: Again it really depends on how you are setup. For forms i use fragments, that way everything is standardised. For singular inputs/selections i utilise javascript objects to hide/show errors.

Comment: Have you got some examples of this, Aeseir? That would be an answer to my question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What I like to do is replace the entire form when an error occurs. The following is a super primitive example. I'm not going to use a ton of fragments for rendering a form... just keeping it simple.

This was written in a Spring 4.2.1 and Thymeleaf 2.1.4

A basic class representing a user info form: UserInfo.java

```
package myapp.forms;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class UserInfo {
  @Email
  private String email;
  @Size(min = 1, message = "First name cannot be blank")
  private String firstName;
}
```

The controller: UsersAjaxController.java

```
import myapp.forms.UserInfo;
import myapp.services.UserServices;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

@Controller
@Transactional
@RequestMapping("/async/users")
public class UsersAjaxController {
  @Autowired
  private UserServices userServices;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/saveUserInfo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String saveUserInfo(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userInfo") UserInfo userInfo,
                             BindingResult result,
                             Model model)  {
    // if any errors, re-render the user info edit form
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "fragments/user :: info-form";
    }
    // let the service layer handle the saving of the validated form fields
    userServices.saveUserInfo(userInfo);
    return "fragments/user :: info-success";
  }
}
```

The file used to render the form and the success message: fragments/user.html

```
<div th:fragment="info-form" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:remove="tag">
  <form id="userInfo" name="userInfo" th:action="@{/async/users/saveUserInfo}" th:object="${userInfo}" method="post">
    <div th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}?has-error">
      <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
      <input th:field="*{firstName}" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('first')}?has-error">
      <label class="control-label">Email</label>
      <input th:field="*{email}" ftype="text" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  </form>
</div>

<div th:fragment="info-success" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:remove="tag">
  <p>Form successfully submitted</p>
</div>
```

The JS code will simply submit the form to the URL provided in the form action attribute. When the response is returned to the JS callback, check for any errors. If there are errors, replace the form with the one from the response.

```
(function($){
  var $form = $('#userInfo');
  $form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: $form.attr('action'),
      type: 'post',
      data: $form.serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        // if the response contains any errors, replace the form
        if ($(response).find('.has-error').length) {
          $form.replaceWith(response);
        } else {
          // in this case we can actually replace the form
          // with the response as well, unless we want to 
          // show the success message a different way
        }
      }
  });
})
}(jQuery));
```

Again, this is just a basic example. As mentioned in the comments above, there is no right or wrong way to go about this. This isn't exactly my preferred solution either, there are definitely a few tweaks to this I would do, but the general idea is there.

NOTE: There's a flaw in my JS code as well. If you replace the form with the one from the response, the form submit handler will not be applied to the newly replaced form. You would need to ensure you reinitialize the form handler properly after replacing the form, if going this route.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if anybody's still interested, but I'll leave this here for the sake of anyone looking for an example solution.

I implemented yorgo's solution and got around the "flaw" by including the script in the fragment. There was also another small flaw in that if there was more than one submit button with an extra parameter (which is often used to implement dynamic forms in spring + thymeleaf) the information is lost when the form is serialised. I got around this by manually appending this information onto the serialised form.

You can view my implementation of yorgo's solution with the fixes here: https://github.com/Yepadee/spring-ajax/blob/master/src/main/resources/templates/new_project.html

Whats nice about it is that you can implement it on any existing thymeleaf form simply by doing the following:

1. put the script in the form and make it reference the form's id
2. put the form into a fragment
3. change the post methods in the controller to return the form fragment rather than the entire template

Answer (score 1):

Very little documentation on this but if you are already familiar with Web Flow, you may not need more.  I'm not sure how this technique works with normal bean binding in Thymeleaf.  I would love to see a full pet-clinic demo app use this so I can see the controllers.

[docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#ajax-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it could be considered as a best practice, but here is what I did:

```
Map<String, String> errorMap = binding.getFieldErrors()
   .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        e -> e.getField(), e -> messageSource.getMessage(e, locale)));
```

Then I sent the map back into the ajax response to process in the "success" section.